# Weird response from XHR response

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

**&{0xc420058140  }**

can somebody tell me how i can decode this? or what it even is? Im trying to scrape a site and it was the response from a link i found in the `XHR` section

Comment: Which site - more context needed. How do you scrape. Too broad atm.

Comment: Sorry, it is a car selling site (finn.no), im trying to get the data sent from the servers on each listing. im just using the most basic go template for getting a http response (net/http) and then im just Println(resp.Body) @PatrickArtner